# How to display product description on particular div same page for different products based on product click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do an e-commerce site. In the product page, we have a list of product images and on hovering link on product image we need to display different descriptions for different products. Here I'm attaching some code. This is applicable for one or two product. I  need to apply for many products.  Please help me

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function hide(id){
var element = document.getElementById(id); 
element.style.display = "none";
}
function show(id){
var element = document.getElementById(id); 
element.style.display = "";
}
function toggle(id){
var element = document.getElementById(id); 
element.style.display = (element.style.display == "") ? "none" : "";
}
function showDetail(){show("view-details");hide("view-summary");}
function showSummary(){show("view-summary");hide("view-details");} 
</script>

<a onclick="showDetail()" class="text" href="#">Mirror</a> |
<a onclick="showSummary()" class="text" href="#">Trolley</a>

<p>
 <div id="view-details" style="display:none;border:1px solid red;">
  im mirror
</div>

<div id="view-summary" style="display:none;border:1px solid blue;">I'm Trolley</div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although possible, you can create what you want without using JavaScript. For example, by using HTML and CSS you can make this work and create an on-hover effect to display product details. Here's an example.

```css
.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.product #view-details {
  display: none;
}

.product:hover #view-details {
  display: block;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column no-wrap
}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="product">
    <img src="https://www.thakehamfurniture.co.uk/productimages/antique-convex-mirror-31-L.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">
    <div id="view-details">
      <h3>Details:</h3>
      <p>I'm mirror</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product">
    <img src="http://www.horme.com.sg/Images/product/20131128101131F6MGSX6EGACPH_full.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">
    <div id="view-details">
      <h3>Details:</h3>
      <p>I'm a trolley</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, thanks for your help. But my requirement is different. I just want list of all products i left side and my description fixed in right side

Comment: No problem. I've updated the code to have the layout as you described. Let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
function hide(){
    var all = $('#products div');
    $(all).css("display","none");
    }
    function show(id){
    hide();
    var element = document.getElementById(id); 
    element.style.display = "";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="products">
    <a onclick="show('id-1')" class="text" href="#">Mirror</a> |
    <a onclick="show('id-2')" class="text" href="#">Trolley</a> |
    <a onclick="show('id-3')" class="text" href="#">Mirror 2</a> |
    <a onclick="show('id-4')" class="text" href="#">Trolley 3</a>
    
    <p>
     <div id="id-1" style="display:none;border:1px solid red;">
      im mirror
    </div>
    
    <div id="id-2" style="display:none;border:1px solid blue;">I'm Trolley</div>
    
    <div id="id-3" style="display:none;border:1px solid red;">
      im mirror 333
    </div>
    
    <div id="id-4" style="display:none;border:1px solid blue;">I'm Trolley 444</div>
    </p>
    </div>
```